# Using NPM Modules in Namespaced Typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have a Project (Existing Project) for which frontend is writen in namespaced typescript.
I cannot rewrite all typescript file from namespaced approach to export/import es6 syntax.

However the below code is working fine. and no issue if i add my new ts module or react component as far i wrap it in namespace and call it by Class or with namespace prefix if its in other namespace.

Issue is i cannot use external modules with import statement.How can i use..?since import statement is throwing error.

To be more specific for below code i wanted to use react-redux,

When i check the node_moduels folder i saw @types folder from where the React namesapce is referred
I Assume Due to this line in tsconfig

```
"typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types/"
    ]
```

But when i install `npm install --save @types/react-redux` it also created react-redux folder with index.ts under @types folder in node modules. but it doesnt have the Namespace export lines  how the React type file has some thing like below.

```
export as namespace React;

declare namespace React {
....
}
```

Ultimately..How can i use third party node moudles, especially react-redux in this project.
Or any simple node module and access it in any ts file simple moudles such as "react-bootstrap"
Below is the simple ts file for react componnet wrapped in namesapce whihc is working fine (except import staement)

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'; //if i add this line this is throwing error.

namespace Profile.Sample {

    import { createStore } from 'redux'; //this too throwing error, without these lines my code is working fine.
    export class Profiles extends React.Component<any> {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);           
            this.state = { brand: "Ford" };

        }     

        render(): React.ReactNode {

            return (
                <sect
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-lg-12">
                                <div className="main-title">
                                    <h2>Profiles</h2>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adi</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </section>

            );
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitBOM": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "outFile": "wwwroot/Scripts/site/Profiles.js",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types/"
    ]
  }
}
```

I know namespace is not the recommended approach going forward..but this is an existing project and cannot rewrite all files from namespace to import/export statements.

Comment: Do you bundle your code with any bundler - webpack, rollup, parcel?

Comment: Nope, just build js is called as a script in the project master file

Comment: Is the `tsconfig.json` file fixed or modifiable?

Comment: its modifiable..but existing codes shouldn't break.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, let's make it runnable step by step:

1. Although you did not state it explicitly, I assume you get the error message `Cannot compile modules using option 'outFile' unless the '--module' flag is 'amd' or 'system'.`. The option `outFile` generates one master file with all your code concatenated in it. Since you are using `"target": "es5"` in your `tsconfig.json`, the default value for `module` is `commonjs`. `commonjs` is the module syntax widely used for node.js (`var x = require('x')` / `exports.x = x`) and this syntax does not support merging code into one file, therefore it is prohibited. But you want to use your code in the browser, so `commonjs` is not supported there anyways. So the first thing to do is

   **Insert `"module": "AMD"` into your `tsconfig.json` file.**

   AMD is a module syntax usable in the browser. You can also use `"UMD"`, which is just an extension, so that the module supports `AMD` and `commonjs` modules.
2. To avoid some more configuration later on, you should also

   **Change `"outFile": "wwwroot/Scripts/site/Profiles.js"` to `"outDir": "wwwroot/Scripts/site"` in your `tsconfig.json` file.**
3. Setting `module` to `AMD` changes the default of `moduleResolution` from `node` to `classic`, but that's not good, because then `import {createStore} from 'redux'` will fail with the error message `Cannot find module 'redux'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?`. Therefore

   **Include `"moduleResolution": "node"` into your `tsconfig.json` file.**
4. In your code you define a class which extends another base class. If you transpile this inheritance, a special function `__extends` is required. With the current setup this function is not generated by typescript and you get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: __extends is not defined`. Therefore

   **Remove `"noEmitHelpers": true`.**
5. Now all your files can be transpiled to AMD modules. But to use those modules, you need a module loader. The most popular one is [require.js](https://requirejs.org/). To use it,

   **Insert `<script data-main="setup" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js" integrity="sha512-c3Nl8+7g4LMSTdrm621y7kf9v3SDPnhxLNhcjFJbKECVnmZHTdo+IRO05sNLTH/D3vA6u1X32ehoLC7WFVdheg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` into your HTML file.**

   You can also [download](https://requirejs.org/docs/download.html) it and serve it yourself. `data-main="setup"` means that after require.js has been loaded, the script `setup.js` is executed. This script is created in the next step.
6. require.js needs some configuration to find all the modules. So

   **Create `wwwroot\Scripts\site\setup.js`:**

   ```
   requirejs.config({
     appDir: ".",
     paths: { 
       'react': ['./node_modules/react/umd/react.production.min.js', 'https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min'],
       'react-dom': ['./node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js', 'https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min'],
       'redux': ['./node_modules/redux/dist/redux.min.js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min'],
     },
   });

   requirejs(['entryPoint'], function() {
     console.log("Entry point 'index' has been loaded!");
     return {};
   });
   ```

   In the first part require.js is configured. Especially, the locations of external modules (modules installed via `npm`) are defined. Here the locations of `react`, `react-dom` and `redux` are set to the locations in the `node_modules` folder with external files from content delivery networks (CDN) as backups. You can also remove one of the locations. They are requested from left to right and moving on if one request fails. If you use the locations in your `node_modules` folder, you must serve them from your webserver as well!

   In the second part the module `entryPoint` is executed. This is the entry point to your app. Change the name to whatever you want to be your entry point. If you want the module defined in the file `someOtherFile.js` to be the entry point, then write `requirejs(['someOtherFile'], ...`.
7. To transpile all files run

   **`tsc --project tsconfig.json`.**
8. Serve all files in the directory `wwwroot/Scripts/site` including your HTML file. For testing purposes you can use

   **`npx serve`.**

You can see the slightly modified code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-fermat-ie2ms?file=/src/index.tsx.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the excellent step-by-step explanation.
Two things,
1)Cant i create a single js file from the above approach and avoid require an entry point.
Cox i am struggling with the entry point setup.


2)the moment i add 'export' to existing namespace eg
export namespace Profile.Sample {
....}
it started throwing error for other namespaces ." cannot find namespace XYZ" eg . and none of my namespace had the export prefix in project

Comment: 1) Even if you transpile to a single file, you will have to define an entry point. This entry point defines what is run on startup. No entry point = no code to be run. 2) I actually forgot about this one, I added the `export` for testing purposes. If you don't export your namespaces, then you also can't import all stuff in it. Then how do you manage your namespaces in your code? Do you have only one namespace?

Comment: Thanks a lot again @Peter,
there are 2-3, each is called with a namespace prefix when need to be accessed from another namespace. The question is how can refer external libs without exporting namespace. the reason is the moment I add 'export' the namespace prefix referred starts throwing error.
There is only one root namespace and multiple child namespace.

Eg codes in Profiles.Agent name space can refer the class from Profiles.Client Namespace without issue. and any name spaces in nodemodules/@types can also be referred.